# Potential Loss of Data reading from CSV with decimal

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flat-file, flatfilesource

I have read a large number of questions and answers on this and I still can't get it to work.
I have a csv like the following:

```
Field1;Field2;Field3
CCC;DDD;0.03464
EEE;FFF;0.08432
...
```

When I attach a `Flat File Source`, in SSIS, it gives me the following:

> [Sample CSV [2]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion
>   for column "Field3" returned status value 2 and status text "The value
>   could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

I have already changed the output to `DT_DECIMAL`, with 5 as the scale value, in the advance properties but I still get the same error.

Any clue on this?

It seems like a simple solution that I am somehow overlooking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many values that cannot be converted to `DT_DECIMAL`, you can detect the values that cause this error by utilizing of the `Flat File Error Output` which redirect the rows that are causing errors when loading data.

**Helpful Links**

- [ERROR HANDLING IN SSIS WITH AN EXAMPLE STEP BY STEP](http://www.learnmsbitutorials.net/ssis-error-handling.php)
- [SSIS error when loading data from flat files](https://blogs.perficient.com/2009/06/23/ssis-error-when-loading-data-from-flat-files/)